# Two treatments - How do I compute reliability estimates like Cronbach's $\alpha$?

Tags: reliability, psychometrics, cronbachs-alpha

I randomized my survey, and now I have my data on SPSS (and all cleaned up) but when trying to run my Cronbach's $\alpha$ I have a problem.

Because I have two treatments (sexualised and normal) all my measures are present twice in my data set. For example, “similarity” has 3 items but now I have 6 variables: 3 for the sexualized and 3 for the normal condition.

```
Sim1  
Sim2  
Sim3  
aSim1  
aSim2  
aSim3
```

SPSS will not allow me to combine 2 treatments because I have no data that has answers for the 6 (obviously).

Do I calculate them separately and then get the average between the two, or do I report both Cronbach's $\alpha$s for the 2 treatments?

Comment: What do you want to do with $\alpha$ and how do you plan to use these data afterwards?

Comment: Also what's your sample size?

Comment: Can you present examples of items? The likely answer is that you calculate the alpha separately.

Comment: @Behacad +1 to your comment. In fact you definitely cannot meaningfully do anything else that calculating alpha separately on each sub-sample in my opinion but the likely answer is that you shouldn't be calculating alpha at all.

Comment: Ok for example I am using purchase intention (DV) made up of 3 measures: one being perceived social norm.
To make sure I am using valid and reliable measures I need to group all my items of social norm to get the cronbachs. 
but Because I have 2 treatments, sexualized and normal it doesn't allow me to combine the items for social norm.
I have 3 items for social norm but because of the 2 treatmens it has multiplied my social norm items by 2.
Thus to present a cronbachs alpha should I do them separately and then get the average? or report the 2 separately?

thanks!!

Comment: It's a common belief but you don't really *need* to “get the cronbachs” if that's all you plan to do. In fact, simply checking if $\alpha$ is over some threshold and declaring a measure “valid and reliable” borders on superstition.

Comment: What about the sample size? And what do you want to do with the data afterwards? Compare the two groups/treatment?

Comment: Sample size is 210. 105 in each treatment.
I will be comparing the 2 treatments.

Answer (score 2):

Given what you have stated, you should calculate the alpha's separately. For example, you could state that the measure of social X had an alpha value of .75 in sample 1 and of .80 in sample 2. If there are very few items (e.g., around 3), average inter-item correlation may also be used instead of Cronbach's alpha.

Comment: It is always possible to interpret alpha in terms of a quasi-average correlation, and vice-versa. alpha/(1-alpha) = k*r/(1-r), where k = the number of items and r = (average covariance)/(average variance). From this we get alpha = k*r/(k*r + 1-r) and r = alpha/(alpha + k(1-alpha)).

Comment: Thank you everyone.
Ray you have kind of lost me! 
possibly simplest thing to do is Behacad's first solution.